# How to find image on webdriver using selenium and then display it on WinForm

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I find an image using selenium but i want that image to be displayed in my Forms.

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ab\"]/div/img"));
```

tried something like this, but cant get anything to work

Comment: What do you mean by `but i want that image to be displayed in my Forms.` ?

Comment: I have a picturebox in my winForms where i want that picture to be seen

Comment: Does that mean you want to upload a pic  ?

Comment: No i want the picture on the website to be displayed on the forms

Comment: Can you share URL if it's public ?

Comment: https://www.mafiaenshevn.com/antibot.php

Comment: Can you tell me the steps also, how to replicate it manually ?

Comment: if (IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ab\"]/div/img")))
            {
               
                pictureBox1.Image = (Image)driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ab\"]/div/img"));
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

Comment: if he sees the image it will set picturebox to that image, thats what i need help with :)

Comment: I just see a timer on the web page which you have shared, where is this element `//*[@id="ab"]/div/img` element located ?

Comment: Oh need to be logged in to see it, but say it is any other image on the web, is there a way to store a image ?